# Recommended Survey of Algebraic Systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

In **Pinter**'s *A Book of Abstract Algebra*, he states:

> Today it is estimated that over 200 different kinds of algebraic
>   systems have been studied, each of which arose in connection with some
>   application or specific need.

where he gives **Matrix Algebra** and **Boolean Algebra** as examples.

Is there a book or paper which surveys *Algebraic Systems* (even better, categorizes them according to their properties)?

This book is already 35 years old.  I suspect there are many more modern Algebraic Systems in use now (perhaps many specialized).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure points to this page: http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php

Comment: @HansLundmark Excellent!  TY.